# How do I get the file version from bytes or stream?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I get the file version this way:

```
var fileVersion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path).FileVersion
```

But this option is not suitable for me, since I have to use a non-native tool to get the file that returns the stream. Can I get the file version from this stream or from an array of bytes?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cant do this directly

you should

- Write the file to disk in some sort of temporary location
- Read the version from the file on disk
- Delete the file

Answer (score -1):

In short, no, what you want is not possible with the current tools. The problem is that, as you've noticed, `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo` relies on a physical file to be present on disk. If you look at its internals, you'll see that all it really does is to delegate to the Windows API which does the real work, precisely in the [GetFileVersionInfo function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-getfileversioninfoa), which in turn also takes a file name as parameter, so it's only designed to operate from the filesystem.

A possible workaround would be to drop a temp file with the binary you got from your stream, get the version info you need, then delete the file.

Another option would be to look for a library that can parse in-memory exe/dll files and extract the relevant details directly from there.

Comment: It looks convincing, but apparently those who dislike do not agree. It is interesting to know their opinion :)